# AspNetUsers cannot update custom column

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have the problem with .net identity model. I created boolean variable IsEnabled in my ApplicationUserManager, trying to make a "block account" method. So it's working fine, anybody with IsEnabled=false cannot login in to my site. The problem is while Im trying to implement administartion method for this variable (Block_Account() for example) I cannot persist my changes in a user. Here is a code;

```
    protected void Block_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string itemID;
        using (GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Button)sender).Parent.Parent)
        {
            HiddenField lUId = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("ClientId");
            itemID = lUId.Value;
        }
        var user = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>().Users.Where(a => a.Email == itemID).FirstOrDefault();
        //Label1.Text = user.UserName;
        if (user.IsEnabled == true || user.IsEnabled == null)
        { user.IsEnabled = false; }
        else { user.IsEnabled = true; }
       Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>().SaveChanges();
    }
```

And another try

```
    protected void Block_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string itemID;
        using (GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Button)sender).Parent.Parent)
        {
            HiddenField lUId = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("ClientId");
            itemID = lUId.Value;
        }
        var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var user = manager.FindByEmail(itemID);
        Label1.Text = user.UserName;
        if (user.IsEnabled == true || user.IsEnabled == null)
        { user.IsEnabled = false; }
        else { user.IsEnabled = true; }
        manager.Update(user);
        Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>().SaveChanges();

    }
```

Both not working actually.

So I got the right value from GridView and find a User with a right email, but after making changes, they wont appear in my database.

Comment: Can you check whether the ChangeTracker in the context contains the changed values (just before calling SaveChanges())?

Comment: Why is IsEnabled nullable? Make it not-nullable and set a logical default value. In this case I think IsEnabled is default true. Then you easily swap the value: user.IsEnabled = !user.IsEnabled;

Comment: Do not try and update the context, use the available methods from the usermanager. This means that the second method is the right one. 'manager.Update(user)' should update the user. You don't need the line 'Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>().SaveChanges();'

Comment: It seems to me that itemId contains the value of ClientId and not an email. So FindByEmail is not going to find anything. This means that user is null and an exception will be thrown at the next line. After the FindByEmail first check if user is null.